# Week / Year picker jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Is there any jQuery plugin available to select Week / Year for example `1 / 2012` or `53 / 2010` just like Date Picker?

I stumbled around but could not find matching plugin. I am thinking of simple selection box but seems picker would give good UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done that for 1 of my projects restyling jquery UI datepicker. Also getting week number from date is not as simple as it seems: http://brainhog.blogspot.ie/2011/07/get-me-week.html

Anyways, here's the complete solution:

css:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 2px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td { padding: 0; border: 1px solid #D3D3D3; border-width: 1px 0; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td:last-child { border-right-width: 1px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar td a { border: none; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover td { border-color: #FCEFA1; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover td a { background: #FCFAF1; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover .ui-datepicker-week-col,
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr .ui-datepicker-week-col { background: #757575; padding: 0.2em; color: #fff; text-align: right; border: 1px solid #3F3F3F; }
#weekPicker { font-size: .7em; }
```

js:

```
$('#weekPicker').datepicker({ 
    firstDay: 1, 
    showWeek: true, 
    weekHeader: '', 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShow: function(input, inst){ 
        var yw = input.value.split('-'), dat = getDateFromWeek(yw[0], yw[1]); 
        $('#weekPicker').datepicker("setDate", dat); 
    },
    onClose: function(input, inst){ 
        var yw = new Date(input).getFullWeek(); 
        inst.input.val(yw.y+'-'+yw.w); 
        $('#weekPicker2').html('<b>Week ' + yw.w+'</b>: '+input); 
    }
});
```

and you also need these functions:

```
//Returns ISO 8601 week number and year
Date.prototype.getFullWeek = function(){
    var jan1, w, d = new Date(this);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+4-(d.getDay()||7));   // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number, make Sunday's day number 7
    jan1 = new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1);       // Get first day of year
    w = Math.ceil((((d-jan1)/86400000)+1)/7);   // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    return {y: d.getFullYear(), w: w };
};
//Returns ISO 8601 week number
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(){ return this.getFullWeek().w; };
var getWeeksInYear = function(y){ return new Date(y,11,28).getFullWeek().w; };
```

Let me know if you have any issues/questions and whether this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/dropdown-month-year.html), in this picker you can select the month/year independently. You can probably modify it to set/get the weekend number too.